# How to I properly reference an image file from a script in an asp.net mvc project?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net application running on a subdirectory of my website (i.e. www.example.com/go/) and within a .js script file I'm trying to reference an image which is in the Images directory of my project.

When I use `/Images/add.png` to refer to the image, I can see the image while in debug mode, but not when the application is published (when in debug mode the application just runs on logalhost:port# and not under the /go/ url path). And when I use `go/Images/add.png` to refer to the image, I can see the image on the published web application, but not while testing in debug mode. What is the proper way to refer to the image resource from my script so that I can see it both in production and debug mode?

**Edit**

For some reason relative paths are not working. 
I've experimented with `./Images/add.png` and `../Images/add.png`.

Comment: I have had some issues where images in my projects don't get copied automatically when I deploy. I would check the directory on the published side to see if they are there.

Comment: @Llepwryd Yea I made sure the images are in the directory and I can access them by typing the URL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a global javascript variable pointing to the image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imageUrl = '@Url.Content("~/images/add.png")';
</script>
```

and then inside your javascript file you could use this global variable to refer to the image location instead of hardcoding its value, which as you've already found out, doesn't work when you publish the application in a virtual directory.

Needless to say that this script should be included in the view **before** the script that actually uses this javascript variable.

Comment: This is not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me. I created a js var called imageDir in a global view and just append the file name to it as needed.

Answer (score 3):

If your script is not seperate from your MVC views then just use`var image = @Url.Content("~/Images/add.png")` in your script.

Otherwise, either use a relative path as you know where your script files are and where your images are relative to each other:

```
../Images/add.png
```

Or use MVC to get the relative path of the content and add it to an element that you read using the script:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-image="@Url.Content("~/Images/add.png")"></div>

var imageUrl = document.getElementById('myDiv').attributes["data-image"].value;
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/hbBKs/1/

Comment: I forgot to mention I attempted the relative directory method, but it didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either reference the image from a relative path based on the script so it could be

```
../images/file.jpg
```

Or you need to include some .Net into the Javascript

```
var image = '@Url.Content("~/uploads/file.jpg")';
```

the '~' symbol says to start at the root of the project (Even in that is a  sub folder)